# RibbonComboBox in RibbonMenu of Powerpoint AddIn

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, powerpoint, ribbon

I am quite new to .Net. I want to ask is it possible to put RibbonComboBox into a RibbonMenu? I don't see any way to do that, but maybe there exist a way to hack that? Like in the following picture:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you put it in the ApplicationMenu ?

Comment: I am developing a PowerPoint addIn, so that's why I should use the Office Ribbon. I add a Ribbon Menu into the Office Ribbon, but can't find a way to put a Combo Box into the Ribbon Menu. Please note that there are 3 different components here (Office Ribbon, Ribbon Menu, and Ribbon ComboBox)

Comment: The ApplicationMenu is part of the ribbon : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it seems that the Application Menu is always at the first position, but I want that the comboBox should be put into the middle Ribbon component.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for ?

[image]

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Custom="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/ribbon" x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Custom:Ribbon HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517">
            <Custom:RibbonTab Header="Tab">
                <Custom:RibbonGroup Header="Group" >
                    <Custom:RibbonMenuButton Label="MenuButton" >
                        <Custom:RibbonGallery>
                            <Custom:RibbonComboBox />
                            <Custom:RibbonGalleryItem Content="a"></Custom:RibbonGalleryItem>
                            <Custom:RibbonGalleryItem Content="a"></Custom:RibbonGalleryItem>
                            <Custom:RibbonGalleryItem Content="b"></Custom:RibbonGalleryItem>
                            <Custom:RibbonGalleryItem Content="c"></Custom:RibbonGalleryItem>
                        </Custom:RibbonGallery>
                    </Custom:RibbonMenuButton>
                </Custom:RibbonGroup>
            </Custom:RibbonTab>
        </Custom:Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**EDIT**

**Sorry but the first time I've answered your question I thought it was for WPF ...**

On using the XML Ribbon, that's really interesting because I thought the Office ribbon features would be on par with the WPF one but it doesn't seem to be the case !

I have tried to achieve the same thing using the designer and an XML file but they both won't let me do so : to have a menu inside a gallery. And by checking in Word 2013, effectively **none of the controls in all tabs** do show this feature.

References :

[Ribbon Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386097.aspx)

[How to: Export a Ribbon from the Ribbon Designer to Ribbon XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386297.aspx)

[Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using Ribbon XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx)

I would suggest you to ask a question @ https://ux.stackexchange.com/, there's probably another approach on what options you're trying to provide to the user, you can also update your question and I'll try to address it.

**EDIT 2**

Unfortunately you can't put whatever you want into containers, here are a few approaches of how you could achieve the same functionality :

Gallery

[image]

Menu

[image]

SplitButton

[image]

Personally I'd go for the Menu as it's the clearest of all, now SplitButton mimics the most your initial example though it expands on the right instead of bottom.

If you look at how Word achieves it :

[image]

[image]

The most used are on the ribbon, the custom zoom is on the bottom.

Comment: Yes, exactly it is what I want. I see that there are two ways to create a ribbon. One is use the standard built-in ribbon, another one is use the xml to build the advanced Ribbon. Now I am using the standard one. Can I convert from the standard one to the Advanced XML Ribbon? Or I have to remove all the standard one and re-build the Ribbon using XML?

Comment: I did post on the site (ux.stackexchange.com) that you suggested, but they complain about it.

Comment: See my 2nd edit for alternatives, regarding UX you probably haven't asked it properly, it's just like in here if it doesn't fit the site it's likely to be closed. I think you should just continue on coding your application and test over and over, add new features and by regularly testing you will see what's the best approach to present the feature. I perfectly understand your desire of wanting it that way but sometimes it's not possible unless you do everything from scratch but in the case of the ribbon you don't have that option. Don't forget to mark the answer if you're satisfied with it :D